# Excel logical test for constant over a selection of cells

Tags: excel

I have been looking for other topics that cover this, but have not been able to find any suggestions. It might just be that I am not exactly sure what the problem/solution is called.

I have a panel data (longitunidal) that looks like this:

**Drug  Company**

DrugA Company_name_t1

DrugA Company_name_t2

DrugA Company_name_t3

DrugA Company_name_t4

DrugB Company_name_t1

DrugB Company_name_t2

DrugB Company_name_t3

DrugB Company_name_t4

I want to create a new column called "ChangeName" where I insert a 0 if the company_name is the same for a given drug. Ie. if for DrugA the company changes name at time3, then the cell in the new row "ChangeName" will be empty, while if the Company_name for DrugB across all four time observations is the same, then the cells in column "ChangeName" will include a 0 for all rows with DrugB. See example below.

**Drug  Company ChangeName**

DrugA Company_name_t1

DrugA Company_name_t2

DrugA Company_name_t3

DrugA Company_name_t4

DrugB Company_name_t1 0

DrugB Company_name_t2 0

DrugB Company_name_t3 0

DrugB Company_name_t4 0

Does anyone knows how to do this in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your example data is a real mess, in comments for @LJ01's answer you show what you need:

> *What I am looking for is to insert a "0" IF the Company_name is the same for ALL observations of DrugX*

Then, the idea is to compare count of DrugA with count of DrugA with CompanyName. If they are equal, your condition is met.
This may look like that:

```
= if(countif($A$1:$A$3000;A1)=countifs($A$1:$A$3000;A1;$B$1:$B$3000;B1);0;"")
```

Comment: I do realise the data presentation was not that good, so apologies for that. 

Your function solved the problem. Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your drug name is in column b;

```
=Countifs($b$1:b1,b1)
```

Formula in row 1 and drag down

This only works in more recent version - I think 2007 on

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem. The command you provided just counts how many times the Company_name has already appeared, counting upwards as you move down one row. 

What I am looking for is to insert a "0" IF the Company_name is the same for ALL observations of DrugX.